# speed up paperclip image uploading using html5 canvas image resize before direct http post to s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, file-upload, paperclip

I have found other posts about speeding up paperclip uploads to s3 but most of them involve flash or a background delayed job to post process the images.

It occurs to me that the fastest way to upload images is to go direct between the client's browser and amazon s3 by constructing an http post directly to s3, leaving rails controller completely out of the file upload.

And with HTML5 canvas and new browsers as powerful as the are, it should be possible to do the image resize right on the client side without the need for scheduling background jobs with rmagick and delayed job.

I haven't found any library that does this (perhaps someone will post a gist or help me create one):

1. Allow user to upload file or files(s)
2. The files are resized as
   multiple thumbnails first, right in the browser.
3. The data is transfered to amz s3.
4. We create new models in the rails application and set the model attributes that allow access to the s3 urls.

Is this feasible?